# Ignore TimeStamps Postgres and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails application that saves date/time information from different providers for scheduling information. I then need to pull out that data to see a range of schedules. Rails is translating this into UTC time. Is there anyway to save the date time without the translation?

For example they'll give me their local date/time (I have no way of knowing where they are) and I need to serve it back to the user the same way it was entered.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting which allows for dates to be saved in local timezones as opposed to in UTC. In application.rb you would want to set:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Additionally, if you are not trying to save *all* times in this manner, I would encourage you to glance over [this timestamp documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html). Specifically, within a class you could add the following line:

```
self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:written_on]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional column and store the user input as a string. That way you have the option of converting it to a DateTime object on save as well as saving the original string submitted by the user. Should give you the best of both worlds.

In your model, for example:

```
before_save :convert_time
def convert_time
  # save the timestamp in the format you need
  self.time = DateTime.strptime(user_input_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
end
```

That way you can get the user input in the view

```
<%= your_object.user_input_time %>
```